# Running nbtstat -A for a router returns a strange name

Tags: networking, ip, hostname

I'm following the [Life Hacker guide](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-tap-your-network-and-see-everything-that-happens-1649292940) about monitoring network traffic. It suggests that I check the devices on the network, and it returned 5 devices:

```
192.168.1.53    a0:1b:29:66:b1:18   (Unknown)
192.168.1.66    7c:05:07:0d:d1:81   (Unknown)
192.168.1.71    20:54:76:92:b4:42   (Unknown)
192.168.1.75    c8:d3:a3:f4:47:6b   (Unknown)
192.168.1.254   a0:1b:29:67:15:68   (Unknown)
```

I was unsure what "192.168.1.66" was so I used `nbtstat -A 192.168.1.66` to get the device name (it was nothing to worry about).

However, I then ran `nbtstat -A 192.168.1.254` - that's the first router in the network.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nbtstat -A 192.168.1.254

Local Area Connection:
Node IpAddress: [10.0.2.15] Scope Id: []

           NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

       Name               Type         Status
    ---------------------------------------------
    PNHUB1         <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
    PNHUB1         <03>  UNIQUE      Registered
    PNHUB1         <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
    ☺☻__MSBROWSE__☻<01>  GROUP       Registered
    HOME           <1D>  UNIQUE      Registered
    HOME           <1E>  GROUP       Registered
    HOME           <00>  GROUP       Registered

    MAC Address = 00-00-00-00-00-00
```

What concerned me was this line:

```
☺☻__MSBROWSE__☻<01>  GROUP       Registered
```

I have never seen emoji used in official device / program names - neither from Plusnet who brand the hub, BT who make the hub or Microsoft which is what I would assume "MS" stands for.

I have a second router as well - the same make and model as the router at `192.168.1.254`. That occupies `192.168.1.53` and I sometimes change the IP.

When I ran `nbtstat -A 192.168.1.53` it returned this:

```
       NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

   Name               Type         Status
---------------------------------------------
PNHUB1         <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
PNHUB1         <03>  UNIQUE      Registered
PNHUB1         <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
HOME           <1E>  GROUP       Registered
HOME           <00>  GROUP       Registered
```

No mention of `MSBROWSE`.

So what is `☺☻__MSBROWSE__☻`?

[image]

Comment: Those are not "emoji", they are characters in one of the sets shown at [Character Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee276763%28v=bts.10%29.aspx).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Which happen to display (to me) as WHITE SMILING FACE and BLACK SMILING FACE.

Comment: So the character codes in the name are 01, 02, 95, 95, 77, 83, .... 02. There is no Unicode involved, and nothing to worry about.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Why does it include that then? it looks like emoji?

Comment: You are just as capable as me at searching for why the Master Browser has a name with those characters in it ;) Just because they look like emoji does not mean they are, they are just what appears in *that* character set to visually represent those values. Perhaps it would be more fun if they used a character code 7 (BEL) ([ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)) and beeped when displayed, but that would become not fun rather quickly.

Answer (score 2):

It only means it is the *Master Browser* for the group in question. Groups and subnets are not identical: you  may have several distinct groups on a given subnet, which is one possible reason why you may find several Master Browsers on the same subnet.

Actually, if a certain groupd does **not** have a Master Browser on a given subnet, then the groupd will not be visible.

If interested, you can find a longer discussion on a Microsoft site, [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961857.aspx).

I believe you may relax.

Comment: Why the emoji? `cmd` rendering issue?

Comment: @Tim Yes. I have never seen one, ever, nor do I see it in your post.

Comment: I've attached an image into the post.

Comment: I'm talking about the smiley faces in the name. What are they?